# ListView Multibinding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, multibinding

Me and a friend are creating our own skype"ish" application as a fun little project.

We've now reached the point where we'd like to create a list of contacts.

Each of our contacts contains this:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ContactList" BorderBrush="#FF252525" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContactNameList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="NameOfContact" Padding="7,5,0,10" FontSize="16" />
                        <TextBlock Text="JobTitle" Padding="7,25,0,0" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="#FF8D8D8D" />
                        <Ellipse Fill="#FF00FF00" Width="14" Height="14" Margin="132,18,14,18" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

But here is the problem, we have 3 observablecollections

- ContactNameList
- ContactTitleList
- ContactStatusList

Now, I know how to make a simple binding, but I don't know how to make 3 bindings to one ListView. I've seen some of examples of Multibindings but couldn't really find one where it showed how to set up the sources (the data that is supposed to show up).

So the question is, how could I make the template look like this? (Theoretical binding of course!):

```
<ListView Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ContactList" BorderBrush="#FF252525" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContactNameList,ContactTitleList,ContactStatusList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ContactNameList}" Padding="7,5,0,10" FontSize="16" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ContactTitleList}" Padding="7,25,0,0" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="#FF8D8D8D" />
                        <Ellipse Fill="#FF00FF00" Width="14" Height="14" Margin="132,18,14,18" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

For anyone wondering, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6fCy.jpg) is how the contacts will show up. All I really want is for the text and eclipse to chance corresponding to their list.

EDIT: To @Kirenenko

```
public class ContactsClass : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public ContactsClass() {

    }

    public ObservableCollection<ContactsClass> contacts = new ObservableCollection<ContactsClass>();

    string[] Name = new string[2];
    string[] Title = new string[2];
    string[] Status = new string[2];

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Its really necessary to have 3 lists? why dont you have 1 list of contacts, contacts being a class having name, title and status?

Comment: Not necessary, I'm just unaware how exactly to create a single list as the one you explained :)

Comment: You have to create 1 observable colection like this `ObservableCollection<Contact> contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();`. You will have to define your `Contact` class with 3 strings: `name`, `title` and `status`.

Comment: But can I ask how the XAML code would look? How would I go about binding the `name` to the top TextBlock without it duplicating the same text into the second TextBlock?

Comment: You have to bind the itemsource of your list to your ObservableCollection, and then, the textboxes to the correspondant properties inside contact.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this, are you thinking of something like this? (Check my EDIT in the original question, formatting didn't work here)
       
I have never made an observablecollection class for your information :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you should have is not three lists, but a list which has all the related info of a user in its nodes.

Like:

```
<users>
<user>
<ContactName></ContactName>
<ContactTitle></ContactTitle>
<ContactStatus></ContactStatus>
</user>
</users>
```

Comment: No worries my friend, I am not very experienced in XAML, so I'm not the brightest at this. From what I understand this could work, but how I would merge it with the current DataTemplate and what not I already have I'm not exactly sure of how to implement it :)